# php бесконечный цикл для мониторинга почты

Tags: php, email

Как правильно реализовать следующую задачу...
Есть ящик на который приходят письма. Его нужно мониторить, и как только приходит новое письмо, нужно делать определенные действия с аттачем в письме и т.д...
Я делаю через бесконечный цикл на PHP который запускается на сервере каждый N минут, выполняет действие и засыпает, и так бесконечно...
Возможно это не правильно и есть какие то другие варианты решения?

Comment: просто скрипт с выполнением по расписанию, крон.

Comment: На кроне минимальный промежуток между запуском - одна минута. Если нужно чаще, то та реализация которая у вас - нормальная. Один раз запускаете скрипт-демон php (который никода не останавливается) и пусть себе работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно еще заморочится и работать с ящиком по АПИ, если таковой имеется. Но, думаю, крон полюбому

Если вдруг гугл ящик вот инфо https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: Спасибо! Т.к. сервер работает под виндой, немного прогуглив решил проблему через Планировщик Windows... Думаю что так все таки стабильнее будет работать чем через бесконечный цикл + sleep...  Был еще вариант предложен запустить на серваке outlook, авторизироваться и написать макрос на vba который будет обрабатывать письма и там уже раскидывать куда надо, но это уже совсем треш)